# Channel race condition

Tags: unit-testing, go, channel

I'm trying to write tests for a simple program that reads events from the inotify bus, filters them, then puts them on a channel. I have seen no issues when actually running the code, but in the last line of the following test, it will occasionally deadlock (about 30% of the time) on reading from that channel, even though as best I can tell, the event is *always* being put on the channel.

Here is the function:

```
func eventFilter(watcher *rfsnotify.RWatcher, excludes []string, out chan<- fsnotify.Event) {
    for {
        select {
        case event := <-watcher.Events:
            log.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("Got event %v", event))
            if isExcluded(event.Name, excludes) {
                log.Info("Ignoring excluded file: %v", event)
            } else if isRelevantOp(event) {
                log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Handling event %v", event))
                out <- event
            } else {
                log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Ignoring event %v", event))
            }
        case err := <-watcher.Errors:
            log.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Error: %v", err))
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the testing code:

```
var hook *logrusTest.Hook
var testDir string
var rWatcher *rfsnotify.RWatcher


func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    // initialize bad globals, amongst other things
    log.SetLevel(log.DebugLevel)
    hook = logrusTest.NewGlobal()

    // Create directory to watch
    testDir = tempMkdir()
    defer os.RemoveAll(testDir)

    rWatcher, _ = rfsnotify.NewWatcher()
    defer rWatcher.Close()

    err := rWatcher.AddRecursive(testDir)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to add watcher: ", err)
    }

    os.Exit(m.Run())
}

func TestEventFilterMove(t *testing.T) {

    ch := make(chan fsnotify.Event, 10)
    go eventFilter(rWatcher, []string{"test"}, ch)
    testFileSrc := filepath.Join(testDir, "TestFsnotifyEvents.testfileSrc")
    testFileDest := filepath.Join(testDir, "TestFsnotifyEvents.testfileDest")

    f, err := os.OpenFile(testFileSrc, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("creating test file failed: %s", err)
    }

    f.WriteString("data")
    f.Sync()
    hook.Reset()

    err = os.Rename(testFileSrc, testFileDest)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("renaming test file failed: %s", err)
    }

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)

    expectedLogs := []string{
        fmt.Sprintf("Got event \"%v\": CREATE|UPDATE", testFileDest),
        fmt.Sprintf("Handling event \"%v\": CREATE|UPDATE", testFileDest),
        fmt.Sprintf("Got event \"%v\": RENAME", testFileSrc),
        fmt.Sprintf("Ignoring event \"%v\": RENAME", testFileSrc),
    }
    var actualLogs []string
    for _, logEntry := range hook.AllEntries() {
        actualLogs = append(actualLogs, logEntry.Message)
    }
    assert.ElementsMatch(t, actualLogs, expectedLogs)
    hook.Reset()
    _ = <-ch
    assert.Equal(t, 0, len(ch))

}
```

Comment: Can you try to change `out` channel to both send/receive, instead of just send-only?

Comment: I think you're missing something here that is consuming your channel value, possibly `eventFilter` running from another test? You also have no way to ensure that event filter has returned; and having a sleep in your test is a sign that you may not be properly synchronizing things.

Comment: @JimB The eventFilter function is supposed to run in a loop, so it shouldn't ever return, which is why I block on the channel receive in the 2nd-to-last line. Point taken on the sleep calls, which are dirty but also what is used in the main library for the same purpose, so I assumed it was needed, given that I'm depending on the file system:
https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify/blob/master/integration_test.go

Comment: Try adding a default case https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations, right now your select block is blocking